# Keep 'for' going if json request is 'none'

Tags: python, exception

I'm downloading a json through an API request.

The problem is that some of those requests return nothing (none) and then an error message shows up and the loop stops.

heres the error message:

```
raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None

JSONDecodeError: Expecting value
```

Here's an small example of how it is:

```
pessoa_file = open('pessoa_file.txt', 'a', encoding='utf-8')
for x in range(n_pessoas):

    pessoa = jsonresponse['Pessoa'][x]

    response_pessoa = requests.get(pessoa)

    pessoa_data = json.loads(response_pessoa.text)

    pessoa_file.write(pessoa_data)
```

i'd like to know how to ignore the error or write something.
I'm not so familiar with python, but i know R. I think it should be something like `try()` or `tryCatch()`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two ways you can handle this. The first is by checking to see if the value you're trying to call `json.loads` on is `None`, like this:

```
if response_pessoa.text is not None:
    pessoa_data = json.loads(response_pessoa.text)
    pessoa_file.write(pessoa_data)
```

or you can wrap that portion of the code in a try/except block like this:

```
try:
    pessoa_data = json.loads(response_pessoa.text)
    pessoa_file.write(pessoa_data)
except JSONDecodeError:
    continue
```

Comment: I personally would move the line `pessoa_file.write(pessoa_data)`
out of the try except and place it outside.
A write error is something really strange and should probably not be ignored silently.

Comment: @gelonida that's the beauty of catching a `JSONDecodeError` instead of a generic exception, it'll _only_ catch that particular exception. So if there is a write error, it won't be caught, and will instead be raised

Comment: true I overlooked that. 
I still think it's good habit to make the try section as short as possible.
So it's easier to see what lines can fail.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Worked fine using the try and the except

Answer (score 1):

If you want to avoid try except you can try this ( if i have the right variable) :

```
response_pessoa.text 
if response_pessoa.text  == None
   continue
   # or something else and continue processing
```

Sometimes i think it's better to deal with an issue that you can deal with before a try except block, but it's a personal matter of programming style
and write code around dealing with getting a None value.